# Logarithmic expression with three terms

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

So, I have this logarithmic expression 
$$\log_5 8-\log_5 20-\log_5 10$$ that I know how to evaluate - the quotient of numbers is the difference of logarithms, so you divide, etc. - but how the heck do you solve one like this with three logs?

I've been able to solve others that only had two logs, but this one confuses me. Help?

Comment: log a - log b - log c = log (a/bc)

Comment: This is an expression which you want to evaluate, not an equation (no equal sign) to solve.

Comment: Thanks for the grammatical contribution. It really helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that $\log(a)- \log(b)= \log(\frac{a}{b})$. Hence, we have

$\log_5(8) - \log_5(20)-\log_5(10) = \log_5(\frac{8}{20})-\log_5(10) $

$= \log_5(\frac{\frac{8}{20}}{10})$

$= \log_5(\frac{8}{200})$

$= \log_5(\frac{1}{25})$

$= \log_5(1)-\log_5(25)$

$= 0 -2 = -2$

Comment: This is exactly how I ultimately solved it. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 4):

**A start:** If you know how to handle the sum or difference of **two** logarithms, you can handle the sum, difference of arbitrarily many. Just deal with them two at a time. For example,
$$\log_5 8-\log_5 20-\log_5 10=(\log_5 8 -\log_5 20)-\log_5 10=\log_5(8/20)-\log_5 10=\log_5(?).$$

**Added:** For a problem like this one, which involves smallish *integers*, there is another way to proceed. Note that $8=2^3$, so $\log_5 8=3\log_5 2$.

Similarly, $\log_5 20=\log_5(2^2\cdot 5)=2\log_5 2+\log_5 5=2\log_5 2+1$. Similarly, $\log_5 10=\log_5 2+1$. So our expression is equal to 
$$3\log_5 2-(2\log_5 2+1)-(\log_5 2+1).$$
Simplify. The $\log_5 2$ terms disappear.

Answer (score 1):

$$\log_5 8-\log_5 20-\log_5 10=\log_5 8/200=\log_5 1/25=\log_5 1-\log_5 25=0-2=-2 $$

Answer (score 0):

Implement the formula:

$1)$ $\log_x a-\log_x b=\log_x \frac{a}{b}$

$2)$ $\log_a 1=\log_a a^0=0$

$3)$ $\log_x a^n=n\log_x a$

$\log_5 8-\log_5 20-\log_5 10=\log_5\frac{8}{20}-\log_5 10=\log_5\frac{2}{5}-\log_5 10=\log_5\frac{\frac{2}{5}}{10}=\log_5 \frac{2}{50}=\log_5 \frac {1}{25}=\log_5 1 -\log_5 25=0-\log_5 5^2=0-2=-2$